# Is it better to use Django template tags or pass variables from python

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm displaying a date on a Django template, and I have a python function that formats the date today for me and passes it to my template.

```
# function [format example: Wednesday 01 February 10:00:00]
def today():
    date_now = datetime.now()
    day_number = date_now.strftime("%d")
    month_name = date_now.strftime("%B")
    day_name = date_now.strftime("%A")
    time = date_now.strftime("%X")
    date = "{} {} {} {}".format(day_name, day_number, month_name, time)
    return date

# view
def myview(request):
    the_date_today = today()
    context = {
        "the_date_today": the_date_today,
    }
    return render(request, "template.html", context)

# template
<h1>{{ the_date_today }}</h1>
```

I've just found a way of doing this just with Django template tags.

```
# view
def myview(request):
    the_date_today = datetime.now()
    context = {
        "the_date_today": the_date_today,
    }
    return render(request, "template.html", context)

# template
<h1>{{ the_date_today|date:"l m F H:i" }}</h1>
```

What's the better approach for this? It's a lot less code to just use template filters, but does this make anything slower?

Comment: Template filters will not make your app any slower. Behind the scenes those are python functions anyway. It is best to keep presentation in the templates, so I would advise using the standard Django template filters for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template method is better. It's not going to be slower.

If later on you need to modify the display format you can do so by simply modifying the template, not the code.

What's more, you don't even need to pass the value for `the_date_today` to the template because you can call [`now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#now) in the template:

```
<h1>{% now "l d F H:i" %}</h1>
```

Comment: @RuthYoung: No problem. BTW I think that the date format string should be `"l d F H:i"` where the "m" (month of the year) is replaced by "d" (the day of the month).